# laravel 8 404| not found error and route list issue

Tags: laravel

I was working on my project and everything was normal, suddenly I lost the connection and my server stopped working giving me error while trying this link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

I tried `php artisan optimize`, and also checked my route list but it gives me only below line:

```
--------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                 | Name                        | Action                                                     | Middleware |
+--------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | sanctum/csrf-cookie | generated::RGn651ZoIReNs5HE | Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers\CsrfCookieController@show | web    
+--------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------
```

and this is my web file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProjectReportController;
use App\Models\Project;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();
//Route::get('/home',[HomeController::class,'index']);


Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){

    
   // 
////////////////Home Controller///////////

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
//Route::get('/',[HomeController::class,'index']);
Route::get('about', 'HomeController@about')->name('aboutUsers');
Route::get('contact', 'HomeController@contact');
//Route::get('/welcome', 'HomeController@welcome')->name('welcome');
Route::get('/users', 'HomeController@users');
Route::get('users/{id}','HomeController@detail');
Route::view('adduser','users.add_user'); //insert data
Route::post('adduser',[HomeController::class,'addUsers']); //for insert user

////////////////Project Controller///////////
//Route::get('/ad_ajxsrch', 'ProjectController@list'); //changed tp from get to post
Route::view('add','addproject'); //insert data
Route::post('add',[ProjectController::class,'addProject']); //for insert data

Route::get('delete/{id}',[ProjectController::class,'delete'])->middleware(CheckUser::class);

Route::get('updateReport/{id}','ProjectController@showData');
Route::post('updateReport','ProjectController@update');

Route::get('new/{id}','ProjectController@detail');
Route::get('p_reports/{id}','ProjectController@note');


//Route::get('new',[ProjectController::class,'searchData'])->name('sm_search');//changed tp from get to post
Route::get('gn_ajxsrch',[ProjectController::class,'searchData'])->name('sm_search');  //pagination reload


Route::get('projectReport','ProjectController@download_pdf');
Route::get('new/{id}/search_result','ProjectReportController@detail_pdf');

///////Manager Resource////////////////
Route::resource('manager','ManagerController');

///////Report Resource////////////////
Route::resource('report','ProjectReportController');
Route::get('new/{id}/report',[ProjectController::class,'reports_num']);

/////////////////Joint table//////////////////
//Route::get('/show',[ProjectReportController::class,'show'])->name('adm_search');
//Route::post('/re_search',[ProjectReportController::class,'searchRow']);



Route::get('test',[ProjectReportController::class,'test']);
//Route::resource('/new','ProjectController');
Route::get('ad_search',[ProjectReportController::class,'ad_search'])->name('web.search');

Route::get('ajaxpagi-show',[ProjectReportController::class,'re_report']);

Route::get('ad_ajxsrch',[ProjectReportController::class,'show_srch'])->name('adm_search');
//Route::get('gn_ajxsrch',[ProjectController::class,'searchData'])->name('sm_search');

});
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the route cache once, with: `php artisan route:clear`.
The underlying issue might be a permission problem on the caches.